# yum update failing each time

Tags: fedora, yum, upgrade

I have been trying to update my Fedora 19 system, but each time it fails with some error.

I tried doing a `yum clean all` but to no avail. The last time i got this set of errors,

```
Total                                                                                                                  63 kB/s | 726 MB  03:15:53     
Running transaction check
Running transaction test


Transaction check error:
  file /etc/php-zts.d/zip.ini from install of php-common-5.5.7-1.fc19.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-pecl-zip-1.12.1-2.fc19.remi.1.x86_64
  file /etc/php.d/zip.ini from install of php-common-5.5.7-1.fc19.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-pecl-zip-1.12.1-2.fc19.remi.1.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/zip.so from install of php-common-5.5.7-1.fc19.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-pecl-zip-1.12.1-2.fc19.remi.1.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so from install of php-common-5.5.7-1.fc19.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-pecl-zip-1.12.1-2.fc19.remi.1.x86_64
  file /usr/share/doc/HTML/de/k3guitune/index.cache.bz2 from install of k3guitune-1.01-10.fc19.x86_64 conflicts with file from package k3guitune-1.01-9.fc18.i686
  file /usr/share/doc/HTML/en/k3guitune/index.cache.bz2 from install of k3guitune-1.01-10.fc19.x86_64 conflicts with file from package k3guitune-1.01-9.fc18.i686
  file /usr/share/doc/HTML/nl/k3guitune/index.cache.bz2 from install of k3guitune-1.01-10.fc19.x86_64 conflicts with file from package k3guitune-1.01-9.fc18.i686
  file /usr/share/applications/k3guitune.desktop from install of k3guitune-1.01-10.fc19.x86_64 conflicts with file from package k3guitune-1.01-9.fc18.i686

Error Summary
-------------
```

Please help..

Comment: Does `yum distro-sync` help with the `k3guitune` (and perhaps other) issues?

Answer (score 0):

You have (or had) the [Remi repo](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/) installed, which included packages that conflict with the base Fedora repositories.  I suggest removing the package you installed from that repo and try again.

Comment: can you help on how to remove that repository

Comment: i remember once installing the KDE desktop.. along with the GNOME one, how can i remove the entire KDE desktop?